# Convertig Json to List

Tags: java, json, database, gson

I am trying to read and write a Json object to my database and I'm not getting how to convert the string you get from the database to a string and how I can use it later tp write back the changed list into my database again.

So when I'm asking the database for the field I want, I get this string back:

```
["[\"pw1\",\"pw2\",\"pw3\"]"]
```

Then I go and create an object of my class `LastPasswords`

```
List<String> passwordList = (List<String>) controllerServlet.getMacroDatabaseManager().executeNativeQuery(queryGet);
LastPasswords lastPasswords = new LastPasswords(passwordList);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String Json = gson.toJson(lastPasswords);
```

Here is the `LastPasswords` class

```
public class LastPasswords {

    private List<String> passwords;

    public LastPasswords(List<String> passwords) {
        this.passwords = passwords;
    }

    public List<String> getPasswords(){
        return passwords;
    }
    public void setPasswords(List<String> passwords){
        this.passwords = passwords;
    }
}
```

Then when I have this json string I try to get it as a list but I don't get the list.

```
lastPasswords.setPasswords((List<String>) gson.fromJson(banana, LastPasswords.class));
passwordList = lastPasswords.getPasswords();
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use TypeToken to load the json string into a custom object.

```
String json = "[\"pw1\",\"pw2\",\"pw3\"]";
List<String> list = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType());
```

Or for an list of list of String

```
String json = "[\"[\"pw1\",\"pw2\",\"pw3\"]\"]";
List<List<String>> list = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<List<String>>>(){}.getType());

list.get(0).get(0) == "pw1"
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work because there are 2 Square brackets on each side of my String and i need to get rid of one pair I think but i dont know how

Comment: Square bracket? Show us. I think that is an encoding problem

Comment: ["[\"pw1\",\"pw2\",\"pw3\"]"]  This is what i meant :)

Comment: this string is an array of array

Comment: Thank you very much. I was stupid and made way to much. It was much easier after your Post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.TypeToken` to define return type of `fromJson` method. 
Then, àter you have the list, you can create a new `LastPasswords` to use.

```
    String json = "[\"pw1\",\"pw2\",\"pw3\"]";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<String> list = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType());
    System.out.println(list.size());
    System.out.println(list);

Output:
3
[pw1, pw2, pw3]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out real quick.

Comment: This works but not with the String I am Getting because of the Square Brackets that are around that you did not put arround. Do I need to get rid of them and do i get rid of them  ?

Comment: I have no idea about the square brackets that wrap your string. Sorry for that :D I just wonder that do you store a list of `LastPasswords`, so they become a list of list of String.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend to keep a `Password` class instead of keeping a `ListPassword` class.

Let us assume, you've a `Password` class like this.

```
public class Password {
    public String password;

    // Getter and setter
}
```

Now when you read the json string using gson, you might have to do this.

```
Password[] passwordArray = gson.fromJson(json, Password[].class);
```

This will map the json string into an array of `Password`. Then you might consider populating them in a list if you like.

```
List<Password> passwordList = Arrays.asList(passwordArray);
```